# How to solve IP conflicts on local server?

Tags: networking, debian

I am configuring the network for a new server(Debian 6), it has a public IP and a local one, with 2 network connections, the server is a proliant G4, for some reason when I connected it on the eth1 didnt work... so, I connected it on eth3, the config file is like this

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
##allow-hotplug eth0
##iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto eth3
iface eth3 inet static
        address myip
        netmask mynetmask
        gateway mygateway
        dns-nameservers mydns1 mydns2


auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 172.168.0.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 172.168.0.254
        network 172.168.0.0
```

The problem is that I can reach myip only when I am on the same network, if I go out of that network I just can reach it... is it a problem on my OS? some other file I forgot? or is a problem with my dns and other things related? my gateways and dns are not local (I mean, 192.168... or in this case 172.68) any possible reason of this? Should I set the oth0 as the public network?

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you hide the private IPs and leave the public IPs exposed to us? And why are you using AOL's public IP address ranges?

Comment: actually the 172.168.0.2 is the private (someone configure it with 172.168 the network server)

Comment: You really should fix that soon, before AOL (or your ISP) notice and you get thrown off the Internet.

Comment: I know it should be 192.168... even if is Local, what problem could cause?? (I truly thing should not be 172.168... but the sys admin configured it like that)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have two default routes. Remove the gateway statement from eth0 and restart networking.